# Proving $\sqrt{6}$ is not part of a field

Tags: real-analysis, field-theory

I'm currently in a beginning analysis course, and I am asked to prove that $F =\{a+b\sqrt2 +c\sqrt3 :a,b,c∈Q\}$ is not a field.

I know that this violates the first multiplication axiom, that if $x,y \in F$ then $xy \in F$. However, I don't know how to prove that $\sqrt6$ cannot be written in the form $a+b\sqrt2 +c\sqrt3,$ where $a,b,c∈Q$. Is there a way to show this using elementary algebra, and not go into field extensions?

Comment: If it was a field element, it would be invertible. Perhaps you can write $\sqrt{6} (a + b \sqrt{2} + c \sqrt{3}) = 1$, and try to find some constaints on the values of $a,b,c$. If these constraints are too restrictive, then there would be no inverse.

Comment: I'm still having trouble. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Are you allowed any field theory? E.g. field automorphisms?

Comment: Basic field theory shows that the smallest field containing $\sqrt3$, $\sqrt2$ and the rationals has dimension 4 as a vector space over the rationals. Do you know any field theory: the tower theorem, for example? If you do it suffices to show that $\sqrt3$ is not in $\Bbb{Q} [\sqrt2]$.

Comment: Using only algebra is a valid constraint.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $\sqrt{6}=a+b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}$ with $a,b,c$ rational. Then also
$$
\sqrt{6}-a=b\sqrt{2}+c\sqrt{3}
$$
and when you square both sides of this, the only surd around will be $\sqrt{6}$, which makes your life a lot easier. You should be able to manipulate the result to show that
$$
(b^2-3)(c^2-2)=0
$$
which contradicts the original rationality assumption.

Comment: A nice solution, which I suspect was the intended one. +1

Comment: Is it possible to get rid of $\sqrt{6}$ without squaring $\sqrt{6} = \frac{6 + a^{2} - 3b^{2} - 3c}{a + bc}$?

Answer (score 1):

Assume $a+b\sqrt 2 + c\sqrt 3=\sqrt 6, a,b,c\in \Bbb Q$.  Then $\sqrt 6-b \sqrt 2=a+c\sqrt 3.$ Square both sides and you are down to two radicals.  Isolate them and square again and you have one.